# sql select only duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table in database

```
username, ip 
A       , ipA1
A       , ipA1
B       , ipB1
A       , ipA1
C       , ipC1
A       , ipA2
C       , ipC2
```

I need to extract all row with a same user with different distinct ip

i.e. results:

```
username, ip 
A       , ipA1
C       , ipC1
A       , ipA2
C       , ipC2
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle Database? You tagged your question with both. If you need a solution that works for both, you should make that clear in your question. If in fact you only use one of the two, please make sure your tags reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is `exists`:

```
select distinct username, ip
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.username = t.username and t2.ip <> t.ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  my_table (username, ip) as (
    select 'A', 'ipA1' from dual union all
    select 'A', 'ipA1' from dual union all
    select 'B', 'ipB1' from dual union all
    select 'A', 'ipA1' from dual union all
    select 'C', 'ipC1' from dual union all
    select 'A', 'ipA2' from dual union all
    select 'C', 'ipC2' from dual
  )
select distinct username, ip
from   (
         select username, ip,
                min(ip) over (partition by username) as min_ip,
                max(ip) over (partition by username) as max_ip
         from   my_table
       )
where min_ip != max_ip
;


USERNAME IP  
-------- ----
A        ipA2
C        ipC1
C        ipC2
A        ipA1
```